# VLOOKUP function not working on Excel 2019 on Mac

Tags: excel

I am just trying to merge two Excels using VLOOKUP function as it is explained on [Microsoft Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/look-up-values-with-vlookup-index-or-match-68297403-7c3c-4150-9e3c-4d348188976b).

Using Microsoft Excel 2019, after typing `=` I can't see the function, and even I introduce the formula manually, I get an error that is not ok. I am just using:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,list,5,FALSE)
```

Where the variable list is just the selection on the second sheet where it has to find for the data. Already checked this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901507/vlookup-not-working-in-excel-for-mac-2011) with no result. Any advice?

Comment: Is your copy of Office an English language version, or another language?

Comment: What, exactly, is the error message?  Do you perhaps need to use semicolons for argument separators?

Comment: @Rory How can I check this information? Menus and everything is on Spanish.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Using semicolons it does not give me problems to write the formula, but is does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by **does not work**?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The result is `#Name?` for all rows where I use this formula.

Comment: Try the Spanish equivalent (according to the Excel function translator):  `=BUSCARV(A2;list;5;FALSO)`.  If that doesn't work, you will need to research to figure out the proper language for your version of Excel.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Didn't know that. I do have `=BUSCARV()` function but cannot make it work. I always receive `#¿NOMBRE?`.

Comment: Do you have any error values in the `list` range?

Comment: Is the `VLOOKUP` formula the entire formula in the cell?  What is the contents of the cell it should be returning?